# How do I break long line in RDotNet?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, r.net

How can I do to break the long line of my R scripts used to run in c#?
For example, if I have this code:

```
engine.evalute("f.rf=function(i) { NBR_ACH<-ALL_DATA[-intrain,1] set.seed(7) MD.NBR_ACH=randomForest(NBR_ACH~.,data=training,mtry=i,importance=TRUE,ntree=1000) NBResti=predict(MD.NBR_ACH,newdata=testing)c(i,round(sqrt(mean(sum((1-NBResti/NBR_ACH)^2)))/sqrt(length(NBR_ACH)),4))");
```

In R, it's easier just we do the  **,** and it works very well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the verbatim string syntax which allows line breaks and put your line breaks where you would do them in R:

```
@"Line1
Line2"
```